# Laravel - Migration to add nullable property on existing table column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-migration

I have started writing small personal project on Laravel 10. The problem I have is as follows:

1. I have users table and within it I have foreign UUID - role_id.
2. I want to add nullable to that column without dropping the table.
3. I have created new migration in order to do the alteration.
4. Installed the doctrine/dbal package in order to be able (in theory) to change the column.
5. The code I have in the migrations is:

```php
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignUuid('role_id')->nullable()->constrained('roles')->change();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignUuid('role_id')->nullable(false)->constrained('roles')->change();
        });
    }
```

But when I run php artisan migrate I get the followoing error - SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'role_id' (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table users add role_id char(36) null).

Would be very grateful for any advice how to properly do the alteration of the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```php
      Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->char('role_id', 36)->nullable()->constrained('roles')->change();
        });
```

Or maybe using a raw sql statement like:

```php
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE users MODIFY role_id CHAR(36) NULL');
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT fk_users_role_id FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles (id)');
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Will try it out asap. One thing - how the code in the down function will look like considering your code?

Comment: `DB::statement('ALTER TABLE users DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_users_role_id');` and 

`DB::statement('ALTER TABLE users MODIFY role_id CHAR(36) NOT NULL');`